# ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed - Database NO COUNT property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Yay...I have found the culprit of `ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed` issue which was happening only in Production environment. 
It was all about `NO COUNT` property being set to `ON` in Production database server -

[image]

This property is set to OFF in non-Production environments, so I was not getting any error in non-Prod env.

The problem is we can't set `NO COUNT` property to `OFF` on Production Server Because there are so many other clients' databases on same server.
So, I have updated my code to include `SET NOCOUNT OFF` before updating the object -

```
var emp = GetEmployees(empId).FirstOrDefault();

dbContext.ExecuteQuery<int>("SET NOCOUNT OFF SELECT 1");

emp.Address = newAddress;
dbContext.SubmitChanges(); // was getting error here
```

However, I am not very confidant if this is the best solution to this problem.
Can anyone please advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked around a bit and found out that executing this `SET NOCOUNT OFF` query seems to be well-established practice to circumvent a server-wide *nocount on* setting.

However, I didn't find a solution in which this was done once and for all in the context itself, although that's the appropriate place to put this statement:

```
public override void SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
{
    ExecuteQuery<object>("SET NOCOUNT OFF");
    base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
}
```

The public method `SubmitChanges()` (without parameters) passes through to this overridable `SubmitChanges` method (with parameters).